# Why is my deleted function not typeof "undefined" in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node.js.

After my "sum" function gets deleted, I would expect the typeof(sum) to return "undefined", but it doesn't.

```
// functions are data in Javascript

var sum = function ( a,b ) { return a + b; }
var add = sum;
delete sum;
console.log ( typeof sum ); // should return undefined
console.log ( typeof add ); // should return function
console.log ( add( 1,2 ) ); // should return 3
```

I would think it should return:

```
undefined
function
3
```

But instead it returns:

```
function
function
3
```

Comment: What's it returning? function, I assume, but just checking.

Comment: It works for me (in Firebug).  Also, you're missing a `;`.

Comment: @SLaks - When you say "It works for me", what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: It  prints `undefined
function
3`, as expected.

Comment: @SLaks - Well... [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dRhvg/) actually give me `Function Function 3` in Firefox 6.0.1/Firebug.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: So it does.  However, if you paste the code into the multi-line console, it doesn't.  Maybe because of `eval`?

Comment: You have this tagged `node.js` - is that library injecting something that the standard `delete` is not removing?

Comment: @SLaks - Possibly. I don't know why it would be different. Any ideas?

Comment: @SLaks `delete` has different behavior in Firebug because its being executed in the `eval` context. That's not the normal behavior. See: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: @JaredFarrish, The Firebug's console uses `eval` behind the scenes and the variable environment bindings on *eval code* are mutable, that's why `delete` actually works there... Try: `(function () { eval('var a'); return delete a; })();` and you will see that `delete a` successfully returns `true`... I might expand this on my answer...

Comment: @CMS - That might be a good thing to point out; I'm sure I would not have caught the distinction.

Comment: I'm exploring functions as data and was trying to implement a test as expressed on page 72 of "Object-Oriented Javascript" by Stoyan Stefanov. I submitted an errata, since I think we're in agreement that the delete doesn't quite work.

Comment: I have edited to add an additional link and an excerpt from the article in my answer that explains the firebug situation

Comment: My experience with eval() so far, is that it needs to go DIAF

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `delete` operator on identifiers (in scope variables, functions - as `sum` - or function arguments).

The purpose of the `delete` operator is to delete *object properties*.

When you declare a variable a function declaration or function arguments, behind the scenes these identifiers are actually a properties that belongs to the [environment record](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5) of the current scope where they were declared.

Those properties are explicitly defined internally as *non-configurable*, they can't be deleted. Moreover, the usage of the `delete` operator has been so misunderstanded that on ES5 Strict Mode, its usage on identifiers has been completely disallowed, `delete sum;` should throw a `ReferenceError`.

**Edit**:

As @SLacks noted in the question comments, the `delete` operator does work with identifiers from the Firebug's console, that's because the Firebug uses `eval` to execute the code you input in the console, and the variable environment bindings of identifiers instantiated in code executed by `eval`, are *mutable*, which means that they can be deleted, this was probably to allow the programmer to delete at runtime dynamically declared variables with eval, for example:

```
eval('var sum = function () {}');
typeof sum; // "function"
delete sum; // true
typeof sum; // "undefined"
```

You can see how this happens also on the console:

[image: firebug-eval-code]

And that's probably what happened with the book you are reading, the author made his tests on a console based on `eval`.

Answer (score 11):

`delete` is only for deleting properties of object notations and not for deleting the declared variables as per [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

The snippet you have posted is there almost exactly as you've it here.

EDIT: The same article referenced above clarifies the inconsistency that appears in Firebug as well in [this section](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#firebug_confusion). Relevant excerpt:

> All the text in console seems to be parsed and executed as Eval code,
>   not as a Global or Function one. Obviously, any declared variables end
>   up as properties without DontDelete, and so can be easily deleted. Be
>   aware of these differences between regular Global code and Firebug
>   console.

Comment: that article you refer to is referring to the same book that I'm referring to

Comment: @EhevuTov: I realized that from your comment on the question