# remove global variable

Tags: javascript

I use [limejs](http://www.limejs.com) and I declare a function like:

```
function up(){
   var pos = global.getPosition();
   pos.x += 2;
   global.setPosition(pos);
}
```

and call it using

```
lime.scheduleManager.schedule(up,global);
```

How do I get rid of the global variable?

Comment: Why do you need to "get rid" of it?

Comment: sorry. I did not mean delete. I meant to move it away from the global scope into the the function or somewhere else. Coming from a garbage collected language, I did not think of the possibility of this missunderstanding.

Comment: JavaScript is a garbage collected language as well, just FYI, depending on the implementation, of course.

I am still not sure what are you trying to achieve. The `global` variable is already there and it's not yours. So you can't really "move" it to a different scope, only hide it by declaring a scope-local variable of the same name, which is kinda pointless.

Comment: By usobans answer I can now call the same function (up) on objects different from global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since second parameter to `schedule` is context object and you pass `global` to it, you could write the function as

```
function up(){
   var pos = this.getPosition();
   pos += 2;
   this.setPosition(pos);
}
```

If that is really what you're asking for.

If you only need to delete the variable, you can set it to null. Operator `delete` is intended for deleting object properties, not unsetting variables.

Comment: yes. I tried it and it did not work at the beginning. Guess the error was somewhere else.

Answer (score 7):

you can always delete a property on an object like so (note that global variables are really on `window`, at least in browser javascript)

`delete window.global;`

if you then try to access your variable, you will get a Reference error.  Be careful, because if your `schedule` call invokes the method later, and it depends on global, it will be gone. Might be better just to use a local variable (with `var`)

[image]

Comment: Absolutely not true. I suggest [this](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) as a very interesting read.

Comment: The more semantic way to use it is `delete window.x` since delete takes a property name. The reason this is important is that this will not work if you try to delete a local variable. For example `(function(){var x = 5; delete x; console.log(x)})()` will output 5, not undefined, nor will it throw an error.

Comment: @juan, thanx, i didn't know that (never use delete personally).  Learn something new every day....

Comment: @hvgotcodes the console snapshot is somewhat misleading. Had you defined x as `var x = 1`, your `delete x` would return `false` and not delete `x` at all.
@JuanMendes also incorrect. Again, defining `var x` in global scope would result in a `DontDelete` attribute being set to `true` for `x` - so all delete attempts would fail.

Comment: @zenmaster, changed some words to make the answer more accurate, thanx.

Comment: @hvgotcodes Sorry, I don't want to be a pest, but that is still incorrect. If `global` is defined as `var global` you won't be able to delete at all. Not with `window.global`, nothing.

Comment: @zenmaster, thats not being a pest, its making sure an answer is correct, so i appreciate it.  I edited the answer to indicate that delete works on properties of objects (not variables), so hopefully that is clear.  OP said 'global variable'; i think he means a variable on `window`, not a local variable with the name global.

Comment: @hvgotcodes `window` is the global scope in the browser. It doesn't really act as a regular object with regards to deleting it's properties as I stated (the `DontDelete` attribute part). ` delete window.global` doesn't delete `global`.

Comment: @ZenMaster: If it doesn't work, how come in the screen shot, the variable is removed and causes an error when accessing it?

Comment: @zenmaster, yeah i just tried in the console and delete window.x does delete x

Comment: @JuanMendes Because it's declared as `x = 1`. Again, had it been declared as `var x = 1` - it would not be possible to delete it. Try it out. It works only in Firebug console. Due to a bug/feature of the Firebug.

Comment: @Juan, in the screenshot he is not *declaring a variable*, he is making an assignment to an *undeclared identifier*, when this happens, and `x` is not reached in the scope chain, an `x` property is created in the global object, which is deletable. Assigning `x = 1` is not technically *declaring a variable*, and it should be avoided, implicit globals are disallowed on ES Strict Mode.

Comment: yes, but nothing in the answer (anymore) indicates you can delete anything declared with var....

Comment: You don't know how `global` is defined is my point. If it's defined using `var` - your suggestion is incorrect. And if limejs people know their stuff - it probably is.

Comment: @ZenMaster, `var x; delete this.x;` works on Firebug because it uses `eval` to execute the code from the console, and variables declared from `eval` are *deletable*, that's actually a feature, if you declare a variable with a dynamic name using `eval` you would probably want to remove it afterwards... See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624250/why-is-my-deleted-function-not-typeof-undefined-in-node-js/7624279#7624279

Comment: @CMS I know. I provided a lengthy kangax's explanation on the stuff in my first comment. That's why I wrote bug/feature. I think as a feature it's obviously (as can be seen in just this post) very misleading.

Comment: @ZenMaster Good, I didn't saw your first comment!. You're right, it's a feature/bug. IMO Firebug should execute the code as *global code*, it's what I would expect, just as many other consoles/REPLs do...

Comment: @ZenMaster: Thanks. Chrome's debugger actually does work as you described. Firebug and IE Dev tools don't, they allow you to delete it. But if you actually run it from the webpage (or the URL) then all browsers behave correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not referencing that function anywhere else, why not just:

```
lime.scheduleManager.schedule(function (){ 
   var pos = global.getPosition(); 
   pos.x += 2; 
   global.setPosition(pos); 
}, global);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean mark it so it can be garbage collected, you can just set the reference to null. If there are no other references, the object will be gc'd next time the gc kicks in.

Answer (score -1):

In regular javascript it would be:

```
delete global.myVar
```

or

```
delete pos
```

Not 100% sure if this will work in limejs (never used it) but worth a try.